# How to access different menus and tabs in webpage?

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to VBA.

I have to open a certain webpage in IE. That webpage has a menu on the left side and in each menu there are different tabs.

I have to check all these menus & tabs are up. Along with that I have to check for errors on these pages (displayed if any).

I have been able to write code to open the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

here is a bit of code I wrote some months ago. It retrieves the HTML Dom of a webpage and tries to find elements/IDs/classes within that DOM and returns either their text or html.

Maybe you can use it to find your menus/tabs and check if their content is corret. Furthermore the HTMLDocument/IHTMLElement classes of VBA could be useful for you.

As a note: It requires the Microsoft Internet Controls and Microsoft HTML Object Library references.

```
Public Function GetWebPage(url As String, Optional resultType As String = "innerText", Optional selector As Variant) As Variant
Dim oBrowser As InternetExplorer
Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim docText As String
Dim arrSelector As Variant
Dim element As IHTMLElement
Dim i As Long
Dim tmpElementName As String
Dim timer As Long
Const waitTime = 12000

'// set the browser object to a new IE instance
Set oBrowser = New InternetExplorer
oBrowser.Silent = True
oBrowser.Visible = False
oBrowser.Navigate url '// navigate to the given page

'// wait until the page is loaded, requires the sleep api of windows
timer = 0
Do
    timer = timer + 1
    Sleep 10
Loop Until oBrowser.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or timer > waitTime

'// if the page is loaded
If oBrowser.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE Then
    Set HTMLDoc = oBrowser.Document '// retrieve the document


    '// if a selector was given
    If Not IsMissing(selector) Then
        '// get the temporary element name, this assumes the selector contains a '#' or a '.'
        '// to represent an id or a class
        tmpElementName = Mid(selector, 2)

        '// check if it's an id, a class or a simple element and retrieve it
        If Left(selector, 1) = "#" Then
                Set element = HTMLDoc.getElementById(tmpElementName)
        ElseIf Left(selector, 1) = "." Then
                Set element = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName(tmpElementName)
        Else
                Set element = HTMLDoc.body
        End If
    Else
        Set element = HTMLDoc.body
    End If

    '// get either inner text or html, depending on selection
    If Not element Is Nothing Then
        If resultType = "innerText" Then
            docText = element.innerText
        ElseIf resultType = "innerHTML" Then
            docText = element.innerHTML
        End If
    End If

    '// clean up everything and return
    Set element = Nothing
    HTMLDoc.Close
    Set HTMLDoc = Nothing

    GetWebPage = IIf(docText = "", Null, docText)
Else
    GetWebPage = Null
End If

oBrowser.Quit
Set oBrowser = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Plasher, thanks for the answer, but being new to VB and macros I am completely missing the link of the code from the selector section onwards. What exactly is selector and what does # & . represent in that.

Comment: Selector references a **CSS selector** you want to select. As you try to select the menus/tabs you have to define a CSS selector in the HTML for them. Best would be if they have a CSS class or a CSS id. For example if your first menu tab has the id `menu1_tab1` you could pass `"#menu1_tab1"` as the selector argument. Then the function would return either the inner text or the inner html of the first menu tab.